# Show $\Gamma \vdash \lnot \bot$.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Working on the book: Dirk van Dalen. "*Logic and Structure (Universitext)*".

**Proof:**

I will add an assumption of $\bot$ to the set $\Gamma$
$$
\Gamma \cup \{\bot\}
$$

Then, using the **$\to I$** rule and cancelling the hypothesis $\bot$,
$$
\Gamma \vdash \bot \to \bot
$$

(*$\bot \to \bot$ is an abbreviation for $\lnot \bot$*)

Therefore,
$$
\Gamma \vdash \lnot \bot
$$

- Is my proof correct ?
- The book uses a letter $D$ to denote an arbitrary derivation. How can I incorporate it in the proof ?

Comment: Yes, it's that trivial. Also, it's of course just a special case of $\varphi \rightarrow \varphi,$ which is proved in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @md2perpe. I see it is trivial. Though, there are some trivial proofs that are quite difficult to set-up. Do you think I added $\bot$ as an assumption in a correct manner ? Is my notation adequate ?

Comment: Yes, I think that it looks good.

Comment: Thank you, @md2perpe.